# MySQL - LEFT JOIN where nothing is found

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got the following query :

```
SELECT      budgets_income.income_amount, budgets_income.rule_type, budgets_income_rules.day_of_week, budgets_income_rules.interval_week, budgets_income_rules.fixed_day, budgets_income_rules.last_day_month, budgets_income_rules.date_start, budgets_income_rules.date_end
FROM        budgets_income
LEFT JOIN   budgets_income_rules USING (income_id)
WHERE       budgets_income.account_id = :account_id
    AND
    (
        budgets_income_rules.date_start <= :date_end
    )
```

If `budgets_income.rule_type` is equal to 1 or 2, then in the table `budgets_income_rules` there's a rule in there that I get with the `LEFT JOIN` - this is fine.

Now, sometime if the rule is equal to 0, it means that the rule doesn't exist. Since the rule doesn't exist, the field `budgets_income_rules.date_start` doesn't either - meaning that the row won't be fetch with the others (because of the `WHERE budgets_income_rules.date_start <= :date_end`).

I tried these things :

- First of all, I did this :

  ```
  AND
  (
      budgets_income_rules.date_start <= :date_end
          OR
      budgets_income_rules.date_start NOT EXISTS
  )
  ```

  Didn't work out so well because it doesn't work at all.
- After that, I did anoter attempt like this :

  ```
  AND
  (
      budgets_income_rules.date_start <= :date_end
          OR
      budgets_income_rules.date_start IS NULL
  )
  ```

That did work by logic because if MySQL does not find the row in the `LEFT JOIN`, then the column is set to `NULL`.

Now my question, is there a better way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your way is fine.  `IS NULL` is the standard method to find out if a left joined row doesn't exist.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks to do the confirmation. However, I wanted a way to know, like gandaliter said in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you will also get rows where `date_start` is NULL in the record. You could use the id of the budgets_income_rules table to test for NULL, because that will only be NULL in the join query where the row doesn't exist.

```
budgets_income_rules.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I like you way and it's working ! Thanks a lot. Here's what I added to the `SELECT` statement : `IF(budgets_income_rules.income_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS has_rule`

Comment: Great. Your if call is perhaps more commonly expressed as `budgets_income_rules.income_id IS NOT NULL`, and not quite sure why you need to select it, can you not just put it directly in the where (without even listing income_id in the field list at all)?

Comment: Because if there's no rule, it mean that the income must be treat as a single entry (one unique income) and a rule may be a paycheck each 2 weeks or something similar. It can happen that a rule does not have a start name. Why I don't put in the WHERE ? Give less work to MySQL and I do it in PHP using the IF - it's faster then a WHERE.

Comment: I don't quite understand the context here, but I think you're saying that you want to select the rows anyway but have a quick way of telling from PHP whether they have a rule or not, in which case you are correct to put it in the select and not have a condition on it. I would be surprised if it were faster to do that though, as MySQL has to do pretty much the same thing in each case, and PHP has extra work to do when it has to filter out the !has_rules. I would say it's only better if you want to use the records with !has_rule in some way. If I'm wrong and it's actually faster then great.

Comment: Yes, it's quicker. It's faster - the select statement look for the column value in the row and apply the result to it. The WHERE has to use the INDEXES and do a "search" ... it's slower (we talk about maybe few ms here).